# image injection to saucelabs with appium

Tags: java, android, testng, appium, saucelabs

I faced a problem when saucelabs image injection. I use Appium and TestNG. These are device logs;

```
2093513:13:21 W ImageReader_JNI : Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers
```

I also set true `sauceLabsImageInjectionEnabled` and `autoGrantPermissions` parameters true. Below code is used for injecting the image.

```
String qrCodeImage = null;
    try {
       qrCodeImage = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(toByteArray(
           getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/qrcode.png")));
      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("sauce:inject-image=" + qrCodeImage);
      Thread.sleep(10000);

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When Appium logs are examined,I see no related thing in there. I don't figure it out how can solve that. Can anyone help?

ANSWER

```
try {
     ((AndroidDriver) driver).pushFile(remotePathForImg, new File(localPathForImg));
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

You must assign remote path and image path.

Comment: First of all I think it's better to get in contact with Sauce Support. Secondly, does the image injection work when you execute a live test on a real device?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

You can find here:
https://github.com/saucelabs-training/demo-java/tree/master/appium-examples/src/test/java/com/realdevice/unifiedplatform/image_injection

an image injection example in Java + JUnit4

Comment: Actually, I have used this project.

Comment: I doesn't work for me. Then I have contacted saucelabs. They said what I can use pushFile method.